# Ionic emulate ios: Session could not be started

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to emulate my application on ios but nothig **works for me**. I've been searching for **two days** about the error and all workarounds i've found doesn't work for me. I'm running OSX Yosemite, Xcode 6.1.1, Cordova 4.2.0, Ionic 1.3.8, Ios-Sim 3.1.1. This is the ouput:

```
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **

2015-03-01 20:07:08.576 ios-sim[5970:3191481] stderrPath: /path/to/myapp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
2015-03-01 20:07:08.577 ios-sim[5970:3191481] stdoutPath: /path/to/myapp/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator session timed out." UserInfo=0x7ff3d370ff10 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}
Error: /path/to/myapp/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

I really don't know what to do. I already tried all worarounds I've found on internet: change files permissions, running as sudo, reset settings of emulator, open xcode before emulating my app, reinstalling cordova, etc, etc. No one works. Hope you can help me, guys! If you need further information, please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried `ionic prepare ios` and then open the project in `xcode` and run it from there? That is a common build path for these types of applications.

Comment: Actually no. So, every time I want to run my app in emulator mode, I will have to build (in order to copy my www to the www ios project) and then open xcode and run it from there? I think that's pretty annoying and take more time than just running instead of using ionic emulate ios. It suppose to be working, but even Ionic doesn't answer any of this issues. Btw, I ran my app through emulator from xcode but the emulator crashes. After that I reopen the emulator and I was able to enter.

Comment: have you tried `cordova run ios` ?

Comment: Getting the same error with alternate info: `Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Simulator session timed out." UserInfo=0x7fe9b8564aa0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator session timed out.}
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /Users/juanpablob/Sites/udd/corpartes/corpartes-app/corpartes/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project`

Comment: same issues with me too.. did u have any joy?

Comment: after adding the iOS platform, go to platform/iOS folder and here you can open your project directly into xcode. but here www directry will be in read only mode.

Comment: have you opened safari developer with a device attached? Check the console for any errors and hopefully something will give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the permissions on directories it was using the whoami command

This seemed to work for me:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/Documents/yourdirectory
```