# Emulate iOS with ionic, current emulation fails with error: Timed out waiting for device to boot.

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, osx-yosemite

I'm using Ionic and the stuff below. Ionic's serve command, the iOS add platform and build commands work well.

- OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
- Node Version: v0.12.2
- Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.3.22
- Xcode version: Xcode 6.3.1 Build version 6D1002
- ios-sim version: 3.1.1
- ios-deploy version: 1.5.0

When using the emulation command the iOS emulator starts up but never launches the app ending in the following error:

```
Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=2 "Timed out waiting for device to boot" UserInfo=0x7fa1240020c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out waiting for device to boot}
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args: launch,/Users/user/Apps/mySide/platforms/ios/build/emulator/mySide.app,--devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/user/Apps/mySide/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/user/Apps/mySide/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
Error: /Users/user/Apps/mySide/platforms/ios/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

Research on this subject brought up this question: [Ionic emulate ios: Session could not be started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800841/ionic-emulate-ios-session-could-not-be-started), which led me to a workaround migrating my project to Xcode and emulating it there which does work. Its also worth noting that the error message is different in both questions.

So my question is about actually using (fixing) ionic's `ionic emulate ios` command to emulate my iOS app; any clarification on why this is happening will also be much appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue.. any joy?

Comment: No, besides the Xcode migration I haven't found another way of emulating BUT if your using Ionic get the Ionic View app which works better for me because I can test camera, audio and so on. Here the [link](http://view.ionic.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Installing the new version of the Ionic CLI worked for me. Have a look at this [thread](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/new-cordova-5/21558/6) . Use the Github master branch.

Comment: I am current using Ionic CLI version 1.3.22 - is that what are using too thanks?

Comment: The current CLI is 1.4.3